# How to override your Propertyfile for jUnit (maven)

Tags: maven, properties, overriding

I have a Propertyfile `config.properties` in which I store a Path which a class loads to read Files.
The properties are loaded like this:

```
public class PropertyConfig {
private static final Properties properties = new Properties();

static {
    try {
        ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        properties.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
    }
}

public static String getSetting(String key) {
    return properties.getProperty(key);
}

}
```

and the call in the relevant class is like this:

```
private static File savedGamesFolder = new File(PropertyConfig.getSetting("folder_for_saved_games"));
```

For testing purposes I want to be able to change the path to a test directory, or change the whole Property-file in a jUnit-TestCase. How can achieve this?

I'm using Maven if that helps.

Comment: If you place the `config.properties` at `src/main/resources`, it would be able to place the new one at `src/test/resources`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have your config.properties in

```
src/main/resources/config.properties
```

*Note: you should nevertheless have your properties files somewhere in `src/main/resources`*

Place your test configuration in

```
src/main/test/config.properties
```

That's it. No need to change your code.